# Plot axis label disappears by copy & paste

Tags: plotting

I am using Mathematica 13.1 for Mac. When I tried to copy and paste a figure to presentation software (PowerPoint or KeyNote), some of the axis labels disappeared. Is there any way to circumvent this problem?

```
xTable = Table[x, {x, -6, 6, 0.1}];
yTable = Sin[xTable];
p = ListLinePlot[
  Transpose[{xTable, yTable}]
  ]
```

[image: Original plot]
[image: Pasted plot]

Comment: Please try exporting and then importing into other software. `Export[ "C:/abc.png", p]` or similar.

Comment: This worked fine. Thank you very much!